# "Windows live email" set up for Volusion store website

Tags: email, dns, mx-record, volusion, windows-live-mail

I am trying to Migrate my emails from Volusion to Windows Live / Google Apps. 
Is that possible to create when my DNS host in Volusion ?
Any one has experience in the same ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you a 3rd party email on Volusion. Assuming your nameservers are pointed at Volusion, you just need to set up an MX record that points at Google Apps or Windows Live Mail.
You can set up custom DNS records in your my.volusion. com account.